# Calling a form from a module in vb.net causes debugging issues

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, debugging

I have some code which runs in a module when the program starts, performs a number of actions and then (depending on the circumstances) displays a form for further interaction.

I do this because in several valid scenarios it's possible for the program to start and end without a form ever being displayed.

The code looks a little something like this:

```
Public Sub Main()

    Call Create_Application_Data_Folder()

    ' Parse the command line arguments for all the videos to convert
    Dim totalFiles As Integer = Parse_Command_Line_Args()
    If totalFiles = -1 Then End  ' No valid video files listed

    ' Confirm to the user
    If MsgBox("Would you like to convert these " & totalFiles & " files?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo + MsgBoxStyle.Question, "Converter") = MsgBoxResult.No Then End

    ' Check if there isn't another process running
    Dim alreadyRunning as Boolean = Check_Already_Running()
    If alreadyRunning = True Then
        ' Add to existing queue to be run by other process
        Call Advise_Files_Added_To_Queue
        End
    End If

    ' Show conversion window and get converting
    frmConvert.ShowDialog()

    ' DEBUGGING: Display a pop-up here when form is closed
    MsgBox("You are here!")

End Sub
```

However once the form is displayed I have two fairly annoying issues:

1. If something takes a long time and I hit "pause", I'm taken to `frmConvert.ShowDialog()` rather than the actual line which is being executed at the time.
2. If an unhandled exception occurs, I get no error message, the debugger doesn't appear, control is returned from `frmConvert.ShowDialog()` and I get presented with the pop-up saying "You are here!".

As a result, it's completely impossible for me to debug what is going on.

I tried replacing `frmConvert.ShowDialog()` with:

```
Dim main As New frmConvert
main.ShowDialog()
```

but that didn't work either.

What is the correct way to call this form so that it is displayed but that everything works as I would expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Application.Run(frmConvert)` instead of `frmConvert.ShowDialog()`. This is the "correct" way to call your form from sub main.

Comment: So I made your suggested change, but when I hit break the debugger now points me at `Application.Run(frmConvert)` (rather than the line it was processing). In addition, when an unhandled exception occurs nothing happens, I get no error message, the debugger doesn't appear but I no longer get the "You are here!" message. Any ideas?

Comment: Turns out that I'm running additional code after the form has been loaded by making a call out from `frmConvert_Activated`. A combination of your suggestion and moving this call to `frmConvert_Shown` solves both issues.